# The Web Application 2019 Moderator Election page has obsolete links

Tags: support, election

The [2019 Moderator Election page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/4) has links to a chat room and a faq but both links point to the 2013 chat room and questionnaire. Will the link to the **chat room** be updated or the old chat room will be reused for the ongoing election?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't create these links until the election actually begins, which it did today. Part of the election process is updating them to the correct links, which has been done.